# Does a gene need to be transcribed for every single protein made?

Tags: transcription, translation

There is one set of DNA in the nucleus and one instance of any particular gene. That gene is transcribed into mRNA and then it is translated by a ribosome. A cell has millions of ribosomes. So it seems strange to me that the cell relies on transcribing this one gene over and over again to get mRNA to supply its excessive amount of ribosomes. I feel like there should be some way to replicate the mRNA after transcription. Otherwise, it seems like it is way too slow and having millions of ribosomes makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

mRNA is not destroyed immediately after it is translated once. There can be multiple ribosomes translating a single strand of mRNA, as well. Depending on the regulation of the system, a single transcription event (producing one mRNA strand) could produce tens to hundreds or perhaps even thousands of protein molecules.

[image: mRNA translated by multiple ribosomes]

Image from [here](http://book.bionumbers.org/how-many-proteins-are-made-per-mrna-molecule/), which also provides much more in-depth information and calculations.